# Prevent xAxis of column highchart taking negative labels on hiding one of other series(on legendItemClick event)

Tags: highcharts

On hiding both the series using legends, and then clicking one of the series shows xAxis starting from '-1', when ideally it should show only not null categories.

Using 'ignoreHiddenSeries: false' solves the purpose but again on hiding both the series using legend and then enabling other series tends to overlap both the series. Although on window resize event, series get aligned properly.

```
 chart: {
            type: 'column'
           // ignoreHiddenSeries: false
        },
```

Example for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/t88rc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set for xAxis `min:0`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/t88rc/2/

Answer (score 0):

Grouped column charts work best with equal number of data points per series.
Best solution I have found for this is to fill any missing data points with null values:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/t88rc/1/

```
 data: [49.9, 71.5,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```